# SMPP using WSO2

Tags: wso2, smpp

Hi Followed the blog mentioned in [SMS Transport sender in wso2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771889/sms-transport-sender-in-wso2-esb)  and configured **axis2.xml** for **transportSender** and **transportReceiver**. I am able to send a message **from ESB to SMPP simulator** but I am unable to receive message **from SMPP simulator to ESB**.

In the SMPP Simulator, I tried by adding bot **'t'/'r' to enable transmitter/receiver** and also tried by giving **tr assuming that it is for tranceiver** in **users.txt** but still I am unable to get a response in ESB.

Could you please help in implementing SMPP -> ESB scenario. Any link that describes this procedure also helpful for me. ( I am unable to find such)

### I am editing this to make my scenario more clear

My simulator is opensmpp-sim. I added the user details in user.txt as 
    `name=esb
    password=esb
    timeout=unlimited
    bound=t,r`

I executed the simulator with port 2775.

In ESB, axis2.xml I gave the following configurations
**Transport Receiver**

```
<transportReceiver name="sms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.SMSMessageReciever">
    <parameter name="systemType">cp</parameter>
    <parameter name="systemId">esb</parameter>  
    <parameter name="password">esb</parameter>
    <parameter name="host">192.168.0.2</parameter>  
    <parameter name="port">2775</parameter>
    <parameter name="phoneNumber">94777179968</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

**Transport Sender**

```
<transportSender name="sms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.SMSSender">
        <parameter name="systemType">cp</parameter>
        <parameter name="systemId">esb</parameter>  
        <parameter name="password">esb</parameter>
        <parameter name="host">127.0.0.1</parameter>    
        <parameter name="port">2775</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

> Note: 192.168.0.2 = 127.0.0.1 = localhost

**Scenarios**
**1. Sending a message from ESME (ESB) to SMSC (Simulator)**

Sequence

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TEST_SMS">
   <send>
      <endpoint key="SMSC"/>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Endpoint

```
sms://94777179968
```

I exposed this sequence as a REST API. When I send a message, the message reached Simulator but there is no response in return.

**2. Sending a message from SMSC (Simulator) to ESMC (ESB)**
From simulator when I send message, it reaches ESB. In debug mode the message is printed in ESB log. But I am unable to handle it. How can I configure proxy service/ sequence to get that message. My goal is to get that message and initiate a process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I enabled debug mode in ESB, I am able to see the logged message from SMPP -> ESB.    **DEBUG - SMPPListener Receiving message : lhkjlh**. But 1. Unable to send a response when I send ESB->SMPP 2. Unable to create a proxy server with sms transport enabled, which has to pick the message got from SMPP.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the ESB proxy service code.

Comment: Its simple proxy service with log mediator but enabled sms trasport.               `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SMSProxy"
       transports="sms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="INCOMING_MESSAGE" expression="$body"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>`

Comment: @SunilChakravarthyBinkam how do you call the proxy service from smpp?
have you specified the proxy service name any where in the smpp configuration?

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity. Please check the question and help me.

Comment: Can u please give me a link to download the SMSC simulator. I want an already built version but not a source project which needs to build.

Comment: Found it finally at here: https://github.com/smn/logica-smpp-sim

Comment: @ Sunil Chakravarthy Binkam, when I tried to send message from SMPP to ESB ,  ERROR - AxisEngine The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)... how to solve this