# wso2 Esb : Error while passing SMPP Request

Tags: smpp, jsmpp, wso2-esb

Recently, I was exploring the options supported by wso2 esb for SMPP protocol. I followed some blogs and website however I am getting one error which I am unable to resolve.

https://gayanlggd.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/sending-a-message-from-smsc-simulator-to-wso2-esb-using-smpp-transport/

[SMPP using WSO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721246/smpp-using-wso2)

[SMS Transport sender in wso2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771889/sms-transport-sender-in-wso2-esb)

My scenario is to just send a message to ESB via SMPP protocol. Whenever I send the message via SMPP I get the below error

```
 ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)  {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.validateTransport(DispatchPhase.java:251)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:109)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.SMSManager.dispatchToAxis2(SMSManager.java:162)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.smpp.SMPPDispatcher.dispatch(SMPPDispatcher.java:46)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.smpp.SMPPListener.onAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPListener.java:85)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.fireAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:457)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.access$400(SMPPSession.java:92)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:474)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:109)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:51)
        at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My proxy name is "SmsProxyTest" and the message which I am trying to send is SmsProxyTest:mediate

I am not even aware of the exact message format.

In users.txt I have mentioned the below details:

```
name=esb
password=esb
timeout=unlimited
bound=t,r
```

Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SmsProxyTest" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="sms">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:8080/services/checkMsisdn"/>
        </endpoint>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>

Axis2.xml

<transportReceiver name="sms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.SMSMessageReciever">
    <parameter name="systemType">cp</parameter>
    <parameter name="systemId">esb</parameter>  
    <parameter name="password">esb</parameter>
    <parameter name="host">localhost</parameter>  
    <parameter name="port">7777</parameter>
    <parameter name="phoneNumber">918105735018</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

Apart from this I have placed "axis2-transport-sms-1.0.0.jar" and "jsmpp-2.1.0.jar".

Could you please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Please take care with the formatting of your questions. Code blocks can be formatted with code formatting, but paragraph text around them should not, so it is clear what is code and what is your description. If you can use the preview window prior to submitting, and tidy up as much as you are able, this will save editors some work. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer apologies for that as i am not aware of code formatting , this is the first time i am asking such a big question.Will make sure in future that i format the code so that it looks clean and tidy